# Having two NIC's on a Docker image before it boots

Tags: networking, docker

I have a Docker image with `ubuntu:latest` and a few other dependencies. The script starts automatically with expected 2 NIC's eth0 (which is there by default) and eth1. Because this second NIC isn't there the script crashes and the container is stopped. So using Pipeworks doesn't work as the container isn't there anymore.

I tried to add this to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "auto eth1" >> /etc/network/interfaces
RUN echo "iface eth1 inet dhcp" >> /etc/network/interfaces
```

But that didn't work either.

Is there a proper way to achieve this, or else a hack to begin with :-)

Maybe later having something like "NIC eth1 dhcp" would be cool.

-Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your docker file: `RUN ifup eth1`

Answer (score 1):

I added the required features to Pipework!

You can now [wait for the network to be ready](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#wait-for-the-network-to-be-ready) by copying the pipework script to your container, and running `pipework --wait`.

There is also [DHCP support](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#dhcp) if you specify `dhcp` instead of an `ip.ad.dr.ess/mask` when running the pipework script on the host.

Comment: although I agree pipeworks is great and we're using that now for our client that needs 2 NICs, is there a way to do this in docker yet without pipeworks? thanks